# Runas command in Win 10

Tags: windows, command-line, runas

I've got what seems to be a small problem but am pretty stuck at the moment.
I have developed a tool a while ago, that is used to change settings of the Ewf on Win 7 embedded.

The main functionality of the tool was to run ewfmngr.exe (commandline) with different commands depending on what the user set in the programs GUI.
This works fine in Win 7, but for Win 10, nothing happens.
I do not get any errors, when debugging, all methods return values indicating, everything should have worked.

However the settings are not applied.

When I type the commands directly into the command line everything works as it should.

My application was always started with "run as administrator".
What did they change from Win10 to Win7, that causes this problems and what can I do against it?

Comment: Use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to investigate further. Also try looking in the Windows Event Log.